# Allow Null values to be saved in database

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2003

Im using Visual Studio .NET 2003 the add button works fine when all textbox, combobox fields are filled with data, but upon testing not filling the fields with data leaving it NULL it returns error saying "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

I have a textbox named txtPurchasedDate

My Stored procedure

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE AddOfficeEquipmentProfile
    (
    @OE_ID      varchar(11)     =   NULL,
    @OE_Category        char(3)         =   NULL,
    @OE_SubCategory char(3)         =   NULL,
    @OE_Name        varchar(35)     =   NULL,
    @OE_User        varchar(35)     =   NULL,
    @OE_Brand       varchar(15)     =   NULL,
    @OE_Model       varchar(35)     =   NULL,
    @OE_Specs       varchar(1000)       =   NULL,
    @OE_SerialNo        varchar(35)     =   NULL,
    @OE_PropertyNo  varchar(35)     =   NULL,
    @OE_MacAddress  varchar(100)        =   NULL,   
    @OE_Static_IP       varchar(15)     =   NULL,
    @OE_Vendor      varchar(35)     =   NULL,
    @OE_PurchaseDate    smalldatetime       =   NULL,
    @OE_WarrantyInclusiveYear   int     =   NULL,
    @OE_WarrantyStatus  char(2)         =   NULL,
    @OE_Status      varchar(15)     =   NULL,
    @OE_Dept_Code   char(3)         =   NULL,
    @OE_Location_Code   char(8)         =   NULL,
    @OE_Remarks     varchar(1000)       =   NULL
    )
    AS

    INSERT INTO tblOfficeEquipmentProfile (OE_ID, OE_Category, OE_SubCategory, OE_Name, OE_User, OE_Brand, OE_Model, OE_Specs, OE_SerialNo,
    OE_PropertyNo, OE_MacAddress, OE_Static_IP, OE_Vendor, OE_PurchaseDate, OE_WarrantyInclusiveYear, OE_WarrantyStatus, OE_Status, OE_Dept_Code,
    OE_Location_Code, OE_Remarks ) 
    VALUES (@OE_ID, @OE_Category, @OE_SubCategory, @OE_Name, @OE_User, @OE_Brand, @OE_Model, 
    @OE_Specs, @OE_SerialNo, @OE_PropertyNo, @OE_MacAddress, @OE_Static_IP, @OE_Vendor, @OE_PurchaseDate, @OE_WarrantyInclusiveYear, @OE_WarrantyStatus,
    @OE_Status, @OE_Dept_Code, @OE_Location_Code, @OE_Remarks)

    IF @@ERROR<>0
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
            RETURN 0
        END 
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            COMMIT TRANSACTION
            RETURN 1
        END
    GO
```

My Vb.net Add Button Code

```
 Dim cmd As SqlCommand = sqlconn.CreateCommand
        sqlconn.Open()
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.CommandText = "AddOfficeEquipmentProfile"

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 11, "oeq-su-999")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_Category", SqlDbType.Char, 3, "COM")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_SubCategory", SqlDbType.Char, 3, "SU")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 35, "adminpmis01")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_User", SqlDbType.VarChar, 35, "Ivan")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_Brand", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15, "DELL")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_Model", SqlDbType.VarChar, 35, "optiplex")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_Specs", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1000, "dualcore")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_SerialNo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 35, "sgh5960")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_PropertyNo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 35, "j7h7h6g6f2")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_MacAddress", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100, "j7h7:h6g6f2")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_Static_IP", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15, "192.168.1.5")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_Vendor", SqlDbType.VarChar, 35, "ADWAYS")

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_PurchaseDate", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_WarrantyInclusiveYear", SqlDbType.Int)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_WarrantyStatus", SqlDbType.Char, 2, "IN")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_Status", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15, "Good")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_Dept_Code", SqlDbType.Char, 3, "ADM")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_Location_Code", SqlDbType.Char, 8, "ADM_OFC")
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@OE_Remarks", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1000, "ACTIVE")
    cmd.Parameters("@OE_ID").Value = txtOEID.Text
    cmd.Parameters("@OE_Category").Value = cmbCategory.Text
    cmd.Parameters("@OE_SubCategory").Value = cmbSubCategory.Text
    cmd.Parameters("@OE_Name").Value = txtName.Text
    cmd.Parameters("@OE_User").Value = txtUser.Text
    cmd.Parameters("@OE_Brand").Value = cmbBrand.Text
    cmd.Parameters("@OE_Model").Value = cmbModel.Text
    cmd.Parameters("@OE_Specs").Value = txtSpecs.Text
    cmd.Parameters("@OE_SerialNo").Value = txtSerialNo.Text
    cmd.Parameters("@OE_PropertyNo").Value = txtPropertyNo.Text
    cmd.Parameters("@OE_MacAddress").Value = txtMacAddress.Text
    cmd.Parameters("@OE_Static_IP").Value = txtStaticIp.Text
    cmd.Parameters("@OE_Vendor").Value = txtVendor.Text
    cmd.Parameters("@OE_PurchaseDate").Value = txtPurchaseDate.Text
    cmd.Parameters("@OE_WarrantyInclusiveYear").Value = txtWarrantyInclusiveYear.Text
    cmd.Parameters("@OE_WarrantyStatus").Value = txtWarrantyStatus.Text
    cmd.Parameters("@OE_Status").Value = txtStatus.Text
    cmd.Parameters("@OE_Dept_Code").Value = cmbDeptCode.Text
    cmd.Parameters("@OE_Location_Code").Value = cmbLocationCode.Text
    cmd.Parameters("@OE_Remarks").Value = txtRemarks.Text
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox("Successfully Added Equipment Profile")
    sqlconn.Close()
```

Comment: what format is the PurchaseDate you're passing in?

Comment: if you are passing an null date in, you need to be sure that your database is setup to allow null values.  Each column can be set to allow nulls.

Comment: @Jason yes sir it allow nulls ive checked my database what should i do then

Comment: @Jason, he is doing that part correctly.  He is passing his PurchaseDate parameter as a smalldatetime making format irrelevant.  The only time format matters for dates and times is when you are displaying them.

Comment: How many times do you plan on asking the same (or similar question)? http://stackoverflow.com/q/16232173/745969, http://stackoverflow.com/q/16291644/745969, http://stackoverflow.com/q/16293543/745969, this one...?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, **why** are you using VS 2003?  Are you supporting a 1.1 app that management/client refuses to allow you to upgrade to a newer version of .NET?  You can get free (express) editions of 2010 and 2012.

Comment: @Tim yes its free download but a trial of 30 days

Comment: @ivandinglasan - I'm talking about Visual Studio **EXPRESS*, which *is* free.  Take a look at http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads and scroll down to "Visual Studio Express 2012" and download whichever one(s) suit your needs.  You are severely limiting yourself and your opportunities to learn by using VS 2003.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store null values, you have to use conditional logic in your vb code to either not send those parameters to your stored procedure, or send a value of dbnull.  Even your char fields are storing empty strings, which might not be your intent.

Comment: how would be the syntax and logic sir?

Comment: @JohnFx I wouldn't bother to ask question if I haven't ran out of ideas, already tried dbNULL. I try different things first and researching google before posting

Comment: he already told you the answer, now you are asking him to type it out for out.

Comment: well maybe im not just so genius like you sir @JohnFx  that you can understand every little thing

Comment: Calling you out on lack of effort, not lack of understanding.

Comment: how would you even know im not exerting effort, when you dont even see my workspace and design view of  vb

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPurchaseDate.Text)) Then
    cmd.Parameters("@OE_PurchaseDate").Value = txtPurchaseDate.Text
End If
```

Comment: The IsNull(txtPurchaseDate.Text) check may not be strictly necessary - I think the txtPurchaseDate.Text will be empty string, "" if not set. You could check this by inspecting the value at runtime. Though it's probably safer than not including the check.

Comment: IsNull is not declared sir

Comment: Sorry, the code I gave was VBA. You can use String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPurchaseDate.Text) as the check instead, for VB.

Comment: `String.IsNullOrEmpty` is not available in 1.1 - OP is using VS 2003, per the question's tags.

Comment: Then use txtPurchaseDate.Text <> ""

Answer (score 0):

Why not use DateTimePicker for your PurchaseDate instead of a textbox in txtPurchaseDate.Text you could name your control dtpPurchaseDate then you have:

```
cmd.Parameters("@OE_PurchaseDate").Value = dtpPurchaseDate.Value
```

The Default Value (or the Minimum Value) for DateTime Picker is 1/1/1980 so you could initialize the value of dtpPurchaseDate to 1/1/1980 like:

```
dtpPurchaseDate = System.DateTime.Parse("1/1/1980")
```

So, which means by the way when stored in your database it has the value of 1/1/1980 and not NULL.

If you want to purse with the Textbox then you could check if empty then assign a minimum date value which is actually 1/1/0001 like this:

```
If (If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPurchaseDate.Text)) Then
   cmd.Parameters("@OE_PurchaseDate").Value = DBNull.Value  
Else
   Dim tempPurchaseDate as DateTime

   System.DateTime.TryParse(txtPurchaseDate.Text, tempPurchaseDate)
   cmd.Parameters("@OE_PurchaseDate").Value = tempPurchaseDate         
End If
```

But again it has a stored value in your database as 1/1/0001

You could display it empty in your TextBox like:
Given you have a DataRow named dr

```
If (dr["OE_PurchaseDate"] = System.DateTime.Parse("1/1/0001")) Then
   txtPurchaseDate.Text = ""
Else
   txtPurchaseDate.Text = dr["OE_PurchaseDate"]
End If
```

Comment: upon using date time picker what if i leave it alone not changing anything what would be the default date?